# Automate drawing diagram parsed from input file

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I want to automate the process of drawing simple diagrams based on values in an input file.
I run simulations and often draw these kinds of diagrams to visualize the parameters.

[image]

I have used the following code template, but `\Ip, \w, \ww, \Emin, \Emax, \state` should be read from an input file, and `\w, \ww, \state` should ideally be arrays (I don't know their size a priori) for which I draw each element of the array. The arrows should be stacked on top of each other.

How can I modify this template?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \def\eV{27.211386}
  \def\Ip{0.793*\eV}
  \def\w{0.45*\eV}
  \def\ww{0.6*\eV}
  \def\Emin{5}
  \def\Emax{10}
  \def\state{-4}

  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=none,
      axis y line=left,
      xmin=-1, xmax=1,
      ymin=-\Ip-1, ymax=\Emax+1,
      ytick={-\Ip, 0, \Emin, \Emax},
    ]
    \addplot[->, blue] coordinates {(0,-\Ip) (0,-\Ip+\ww)} node[midway,left] {$\Omega$};
    \addplot[->, red] coordinates {(0,-\Ip+\ww) (0,-\Ip+\ww+\w)} node[midway,left] {$\omega$};

    \addplot[black] coordinates {(-0.5,-\Ip) (0.5,-\Ip)} node[right] {$-I_p$};
    \addplot[dashed, thin] coordinates {(-0.5,\state) (0.5,\state)};
    \addplot[thick] coordinates {(-0.5,0) (0.5,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! The easiest way, if you control the input file, is writing the LaTeX commands in a file and then `\input` it. For example, your simulation can generate a file with `\def\eV{24.3}\def\state{whatever}` etc... The same for the addplot, generate one line for every element you want and `\input` it.

Comment: The other option is generate the data in some csv format and use one of the several packages for reading tables (for example, `pgfplotstable` itself). This will be more complex on the LaTeX side...

Comment: Thank you! I'll consider both options.